# Problem from Introductory Wooldridge regarding WLS

Tags: econometrics, assumptions, weighted-regression

I was reading the book introductory econometrics by "Wooldridge", and in Chapter 8 (Heteroscedasticity), it is stated that (see pink part)

[image]

I could not understand, if $u$ and $x$ are uncorrelated, then how weighted $u/\sqrt{h(x)}$ and $x/\sqrt{h(x)}$ can be uncorrelated. Since both terms are divided by common denominator ie $h(x)$, then it should cause some correlation between the both. I just wanted to know which statistical properties is applied in this case ?

I also simulated the same, and found that when divided by common denominator, then both variables are highly correlated:

```
#R Code:
rm(list = ls())

n = 5000
x1 <- rnorm(n)
x2 <- rnorm(n)
u <- runif(n)

#correlation between u and x
cor(x1, u)
[1] -0.01413626

cor(x2, u)
[1] -0.02338137

#taking weighted x and u; h(x) is x1 + x2
x1w <- x1/(x1 + x2)
x2w <- x2/(x1 + x2)
uw <- u/(x1 + x2)

#correlation
cor(uw, x1w)
[1] 0.9085537

cor(uw, x2w)
[1] -0.9085537
```

Comment: because $$\Bbb E[ux_j/h(x)]=\Bbb E\{\Bbb E[ux_j/h(x)|x]\}=\Bbb E\{\Bbb E[u|x]x_j/h(x)\}=0$$

Comment: Regarding your second paragraph, $\mathbb{E}(u|x)$ is stronger than $\text{Corr}(u,x)=0$.

Comment: I got your point. Then, why the simulating results shows very high correlation ?

Comment: @RichardHardy Rightly said. Because $E(u|x) = 0$ assumes $u$ and $x$ are independent.

Comment: Mean-independent, to be precise. We do not have information about the dependence or lack thereof between other distributional characteristics of $u$ and $x$.

Comment: @RichardHardy Thanks, but still I could not get your point. When I used n = 500000, still the correlation is very high in simulated results.

Comment: I do not have an answer for you. The simulation does not ensure mean-independence between $u$ and $x_1$ and $x_2$ and checking pairwise correlations as you do is not enough to ensure that. However, I am not sure whether this is actually driving the result. You could generate a multivariate random variable with independent components to start with; there are R functions for that such as `mvrnorm`.

Comment: @RichardHardy Thanks, but for large $n$, the correlation between x and u is zero upto three decimals. There is no such assumption between the correlation between $x_1$ and $x_2$. Why you want me to use $mvrnorm$?

Comment: You are interested in the dependence of $u$ on $x$s as a whole, not just pairwise dependences $u$ vs. $x_1$ and $u$ vs. $x_2$. Also, generating independent variables by design just seems like a cleaner approach to me.

Comment: @RichardHardy I tried, but I also gives the same results.

Comment: I see. I wonder what the problem is! Just a piece of opinion: if you updated the code with proper generation of independent random variables, that concern would go away and answerers could focus on the essence.